# Playing macro from iMacro

Tags: vba, imacros

I have tried using the iMacros iimPlay to start iimPlay ("PlayThisMacro1") but I get no satisfaction. Any ideas?

```
VERSION BUILD=8920312 RECORDER=FX

TAB T=1

SET !ERRORIGNORE YES

PROMPT Please<SP>Enter<SP>Number<SP>to<SP>Start<SP>With !VAR1

PROMPT Please<SP>Enter<SP>Column<SP>to<SP>Write<SP>To !VAR2

If iret > 0 Then

    iimPlay ("PlayThisMacro1")

Else

    iimPlay ("PlayThisMacro2")

End If
```

Comment: Don’t merge an ‘iMacros’ code (first five lines) with a script (last five lines). Just apply the Scripting Interface properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
iimPlay ("PlayThisMacro1.iim")
```

Make sure the macro is in same folder as #Current.iim